# Do bittorrent programs damage hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, bittorrent

Someone told me that torrent programs keep reading and writing to HDD for long periods and that will slow down the HDD and may cause damage to it.

Is that true?

Comment: My answer from http://superuser.com/a/414770 applies equally well here.

Comment: Short answer, No. Most of the reads and writes are so small they are cached by the hard drive buffer memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hard disks (even SDD) have mechanical parts or are subject to wearing. The more you use your hard disk from a user perspective, the more you use the hard disk physical parts. So using a BitTorrent client is using your disk. But you don't say you are damaging your car engine because you are driving it, so you don't damage your hard disk either.

The traditional rotational hard disk have [different health parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk#Metrics_of_failures)s (that you can monitor via SMART). The main one that you can monitor are:

- **Load cycle count**: laptop hard disks have a much higher rate than desktop ones due to the more likelihood that they will enter energy save mode.
- **Power-on hours**: hard disks have a "life expectancy" expressed in power-on hours. Much like human life expectancy, some die young while others die older; it is an average value. So by leaving your hard disk on, you are consuming its life time.
- **Reallocated Sector Count**: When a sector gets faulty, HDD drives to avoid them after. They "move" the data (when they can still read the data thanks to error correction algorithm) somewhere else. I have a really old drive which has an increasing rate of this parameter, so I know one day it will fails, but it is still working!
- the list is far from complete, but that should give you a good start.

Those two first health parameters can increase by just having your computer turned on with no service running! When a disk is close to breakdown, some other parameters should be monitored. Those are mainly related to fault in reading or writing to the disk. Check the [SMART article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes).

Comment: SSDs have no mechanical parts. They are subject to wear though.

Comment: @devius that's why I said mechanical parts **or** are subjects to wearing. :)

Comment: @devius - SSD are not "subject" to wear they a design limitation in that you can only write data to a certain cell X number of times.  This limit is slowly being increased.

Comment: @Ramhound my English is perhaps not good enough to understand the subtle differences of meaning between "subject to wear" and "design limitation" in this context. But anyway what I was saying was that rotational HDD have mechanical parts and SDD have potential issues with writes wearing.

Comment: +1 for "your are damaging your car engine because your are driving it"     Very clever example ^_^

Comment: When I was 19 I guarantee you when I drove my 71 Roadrunner, it did damage to the engine, lol. Lucky for my parents I did all my own car repair and paid for the parts.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and uses analogy in wrong way. Certainly driving a car wears it engine off but the wearing time depends A LOT on how a car is driven. Same goes with HDD. And I strongly believe that bittorrent apps damage HDD quite and bit (unless disk caching is overridden) and can completely destroy an HDD in about a year of continuous use.

Comment: @Ejay I did not say that using 24/7 a bittorent client won't shorten your HDD lifespan! My point was that usage is different than damage. You don't damage your car or your HDD just because you are using it (unless you have an accident of course). Now you can buy a car and leave it in the garage so it doesn't get used and will last longer, or you can use it only on highway (with limited speed) which will wear the engine and breaks much less than in the inner city. It is your choice. The same goes with an HDD, you can buy an HDD and keep it in a drawer or actually use it.

Comment: @Ejay When an HDD dies after 1 year, it might not be because of bittorrent intense use, it can simply be a faulty disk (I had 2 HDDs which were not that stressed which lasted just the waranty period plus 1 month!!) and I have add other HDDs which eventhough I stressed them quite a lot never went broke, there capacity got obsolete before they broke! ;-) I still have a running 32GB P-ATA disk which is noisy and won't die! So I do agree and my answer is no contrary to most of what you said. But your statement that continuous use of bitorrent kills a drive after 1 year is plain wrong! It depends!

Comment: Ok let me iterate it the way that expresses my thoughts better. Downloading some files of cumulative size of 30gb via bittorrent will degrade (read, put under constant stress; use vigorously)  your hard disk more than downloading the same content using, say, using HTTP or FTP. Bittorrent protocol is constant reading and writing of very small chunks of data to the hard disk which the mechanical HDD isn't very efficient at. Add a fragmented HDD (who's isn't?) in the mix and you've a dead HDD in a year. Speaking from experience.

Comment: @Ejay OK bittorrent vs HTTP/FTP will "use" your HDD a bit more, much like your car is used different if you use the motorway (constant speed) rather than country side road where the speed is changing more. Now to your "experience" how did you relate your drive death to bittorrent usage? I have quite some professional experience in RAMS and in maintenance, and I know it is quite a task to identify a culprit (if there is only one btw!) for a drive failure.

Answer (score 1):

It's true, but senseless.

It's similar to this kind of argument: "By driving your car to the grocery store, you risk getting into an accident that could destroy your car."

Yes, it's true. But what's the point of having a car if you're so afraid of damaging it that you don't even use it for normal activities that you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

True. It's like a CD-ROM; if you work it 24x7, it's going to reduce the lifespan, mostly damage its motor. So the trick is to only download one file at a time, and don't seed. So it's likely to total UP DOWN only 1. For your information, I use green HDD, which I've already bought four times.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  I am not sure the difference between 3 files or 1 files when it comes to writing data

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the drive type, HDD or SSD.

In the traditional way, the user only establishes a connection with the server and downloads the file from the server, so you only write the file to the hard disk once, and there is no read operation.
With bittorrent, users do not download files directly from the server (tracker), but query the tracker for the IP addresses of users who own the same file. That is, tracker knows who have the specific part of the file. For example, tracker knows the first quarter belong to A, the second quater belong to B,etc. And then you download the first quarter from A and the second quarter form B, etc. "tit for tat." At the same time, while downloading these parts of the file, you also inform the tracker that you now own these parts of the file, and other users who want to download the file will also get your ip address from the tracker and download the parts you own, maybe you provide data to 4 users at the same time, which means that 4 users read your hard disk at the same time. When your file is downloaded, if you are very selfless and choose to stay in the download network, you will still be listed in the node list of the tracker, other users who want to download the file will download the file from you and read your hard disk.

In short, downloading with bittorrent only writes the file to the hard drive once but reads it many times. But whether bittorrent damage your drive depends on the drive you used.

For hard disk drives (HDD), "The primary source of wear in hard drives comes from moving the head back and forth, spinning the disk up", reading and writing hurts the hard disk equally, so using bittorrent is more harmful than downloading directly from the server. But according to google research, there is "little correlation between disk read/write bandwidth and failure rates". So you don't have to worry too much about shortening your hard drive lifespan with bittorrent.

For a solid state drive (SSD), "read operation doesn't affect lifespan", so it doesn't cause more damage than downloading directly from the server.

references:
https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/agcrzv/does_reading_from_hard_drives_cause_as_much_wear/

https://storagemojo.com/2007/02/19/googles-disk-failure-experience/

https://www.quora.com/Does-too-much-reading-writing-to-an-SSD-shorten-its-life